# ORDER BY clause in a Window function with a frame clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I want to take the `min` and `max` for a column within each partition.
See example below (both methods give the correct answer). I do not understand why I have to add the `ORDER BY` clause.
When using `min` and `max` as the aggregate function what possible difference will the `ORDER BY` have?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #HELLO;
CREATE TABLE #HELLO (Category char(2), q int);
INSERT INTO #HELLO (Category, q)
VALUES ('A',1), ('A',5), ('A',6), ('B',0), ('B',3)

SELECT *, 
     min(q) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS minvalue
    ,max(q) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS maxvalue
    ,min(q) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY q ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS minvalue2
    ,max(q) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY q ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS maxvalue2
FROM #HELLO;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [`ROWS` or `RANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#rows-or-range) clause in a `OVER` clause then you need to provide an `ORDER BY` clause, because you are typically telling the `OVER` clause how many rows to look behind and forward, which can only be determined if you have an `ORDER BY`.

However in your case because you use `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` i.e. all rows, you don't need any of it. The following produces the same results:

```
SELECT *, 
     min(q) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS minvalue
    ,max(q) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS maxvalue
    ,min(q) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS minvalue2
    ,max(q) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS maxvalue2
FROM #HELLO;
```